# Static reference ( with :: ) to a method returning an interface

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I have several predifined static "processors" implementing the same method, for example:

```
default double process(double num){
```

Sample :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(Test::processor1, 1d);
        test(Test::processor2, 1d);
    }

    static double processor1(double num){
        return num * 10;
    }

    static double processor2(double num){
        return num * 20;
    }
    //...

    static void test(Function<Double, Double> f, double d){
        // Do something util here
        System.out.println(f.apply(d));
    }   
    ...
```

Now imagine that I have some objects which can provide a list of additional   "processors".

I'm trying to use an `interface` to define those additional "processors".

```
    static interface IProcessor{
        double process(double num);
    }
```

Implementation of an object with additional "processors":

```
    static class SomeObject{
        // Just return one but should be a list...
        static IProcessor getExtraProccessors(){
            return new IProcessor(){
                public double process(double num){
                    return num * 30;
                }
            };
        }   
    }
```

Up here everything compiles and works fine. But now I'm stuck.

Using `SomeObject::getExtraProccessors` I have a reference on a static method returning an interface, how can I invoke the interface's method?

My first try was with

> ```
> test(SomeObject::getExtraProccessors::process, 1d);
> ```

But this doesn't compile giving a **`The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`**

So please could you tell me if it possible to do this and if yes how?
And if it's not possible how should I do it?

Comment: You could use `DoubleUnaryOperator` instead of `Function<Double, Double>` and instead of `IProcessor`.

Comment: You don't need to create an anonymous inner class instance of `IProcessor`, instead return a lambda: `return n -> n * 30;`. And if you need a list: return `Arrays.asList(n -> n * 30, n -> n / 2, ...)`. Also, as @PaulBoddington said, `DoubleUnaryOperator` is the interface provided by Java to operate on a single `double` operand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
test(SomeObject.getExtraProccessors()::process, 1);
```

- `SomeObject.getExtraProccessors()` returns an instance of functional interface `IProcessor`.
- `SomeObject::getExtraProccessors` is a method reference to the static method `getExtraProccessor` of the `SomeObject` class.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a lambda expression instead of method reference :

```
test(d-> SomeObject.getExtraProccessors().process(d), 1d);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to create an anonymous inner class instance that implements `IProcessor`. Actually, if you're going to operate with a `double`, you don't need the `IProcessor` interface at all. Java provides the `DoubleUnaryOperator` interface that is meant exactly for that.

If you want to return a list of "processors", then you could do it this way:

```
static class SomeObject {

    static List<DoubleUnaryOperator> getExtraProccessors() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Test::processor1, Test::processor2));
    }   
}
```

Then, given you change your `test` method to:

```
static void test(DoubleUnaryOperator f, double d) {
    // Do something util here
    System.out.println(f.applyAsDouble(d));
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```
test(SomeObject.getExtraProcessors().get(0), 1);
```